# Web Load Testing

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, blazemeter

I'm quite new at the load testing. I want to know what is best tool for web load testing ? I am currently using Blazemeter and Jmeter for load testing. I am using a blazemeter plugin and then, when I record some actions using a blazemeter, I import jmx script into the jmeter. I have read about load testing many things, but I want to ask you if it is the right way to make a Web load testing. 
What I mean in load testing, maybe I have some misunderstandings in load testing. I want to calculate how fast the website loaded with all of data. For example, login page. Calculate login time and in how much time did it redirect me inside.

Sorry if I have questioned it in the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load testing is basically the request send by client to server...like an api to send and receive response. While, when we integrate api with gui it becomes full application. So, rendering time include api to and fro calls plus page object rendering/loading.
Load testing tools usually works on api level.
If you want to measure page load/rendering time the you can use webdriver sampler and use selenium to measure page load time.
On the other hand, page load time is never going to be constant and will vary in every run. So, need to take average from multiple run.
Some people can be of view to use browser with stop watch to note the page load time...which is also not bad but it depends whether this idea is accepted by clients or not.
I tried my best to give you information without putting much technical info. You can always search for load testing and page load time for further info.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful to me, thank you ! Is there any tool that can measure page load time except selenium ?

Comment: 1. https://gtmetrix.com/      2.https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/     3. Developer tools(F12) then from there you can have the page load time.     Both 1 & 2 is for webpages which are available to public and dont have authentication mechanism. Please check if that suffice your requirement. Else either developer tool or selenium is what I can think of.

Comment: I want to test website which has an authentication mechanism, I should log in to website and then perform a web load testing, so as I understood, I need selenium for that.

Comment: Selenium is to run automatic test and measure each page load time. Manually, you can use developer tool and under network tab you can see the resources and time to load. Please try like open browser, hit F12 then browser the application page then provide credentials and it will redirect and result will update in developer tool. If it is one time activity prefer manually else go for automation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. These information will definitely help me.